# Create a subdomain for every Git branch created

Tags: git, github, workflow, subdomain

I have a development environment and I would like to create a sub-domain for each branch is created in the my Git project.

In other words, if my dev environment is **testenv.com** and I create a new branch called **feature123**, I would like to automatically create a sub-domain such as: **feature123.testenv.com** where the code for that branch gets updated on every commit done to that branch.

The server is a LAMP environment.

Does anyone know how to achieve that? Any tools that you know?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by **create** a new branch? A new branch pushed to bare publishing repository (sane setup), or new branch created directly in publishing repository (not so sane setup)?

Comment: A branch created and published to the project (visible for everyone)

Comment: Definitely look into git hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that "create new branch" means (as per comments) that push to publishing repository ('publishing to project') includes new branch.

I don't know any ready solution, but it is something that can be done by `post-receive` [hook](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html) installed on publishing repository (on 'project').  Said hook gets on its standard input the information about successfully pushed (published) branches:

```
<old-value> SP <new-value> SP <ref-name> LF
```

When creating a new ref, `<old-value>` is 40 '`0`'.

So the update script would create new sub-domain (e.g. creating `<branchname>.conf` file if your web server supports automatic and automatically loaded multi-file configuration) for each line which begins with 40 '`0`' (which matches `/^0{40}/` regexp).  This script could also be used to update sub-domains, for each branch that were successfully pushed.

HTH